# UWP Voice Command Set not working with multiple phrases

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, voice, cortana

When trying to implement VoiceCommands, I use this set:

```
<Command Name="searchCommand">
  <Example>Search for UWP on Bing </Example>
  <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase"> search for {search} on {service} </ListenFor>
  <Feedback>Searching for {search} on {service}</Feedback>
  <Navigate />
</Command>
```

I added these phrases (where the service is dynamically updated in code, this all works fine):

```
<PhraseList Label="service">
  <!-- Dynamic -->
</PhraseList>

<PhraseTopic Label="search" Scenario="Search">
  <!-- Dynamic -->
</PhraseTopic>
```

Now when I use this command, the API only seems to recognize the **last** phrase. So if I use 3 phrases, only the last will be recognized.

```
Command:          'Search for UWP on Bing'
Shows up as:      'Searching for {search} on Bing'
TextSpoken value: 'Search for UWP on Bing' (so the voice to text is working correctly)
```

When I use 'Search for {search}' in the `ListenFor`, it correctly returns the right result. But for this feature I am implementing I need 2 (or even 3) phrases in a single command.

It seems that UWP only recognizes the last phrase. Am I correct or should it be possible to use multiple phrases inside a `ListenFor` element?

**Update June 13, 2016:**

I have created a [repro](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8455721/StackOverflow/37732619_CortanaBug.zip):

[image: Cortana Bug repro screenshot]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, can you share a sample?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I have added a repro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geert, it looks like you're using Windows Insider build 14342. The issue you're seeing is due to a bug introduced in build 14341 which should be fixed in builds >= 14371.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**No UWP recognizes multiple phrase inside a ListenFor**

I guess you need to more than one ListenFor

```
 <Command Name="searchCommand">
      <Example>Search for UWP on Bing </Example>
      <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase"> search for {search} on {service} </ListenFor>
<ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase">search for {search}</ListenFor>
<ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase">search for on {service}</ListenFor>
      <Feedback>Searching for {search} on {service}</Feedback>
      <Navigate />
    </Command>
```

In this way you can cover all the combination. I guess Cortana is getting confused because of only one ListenFor.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have been testing this, and still only get the last element.